# Bind allowedValues to values from a collection in simple-schema

Tags: mongodb, meteor, runtime, meteor-autoform, simple-schema

I'm using [aldeed:simple-schema](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema) and here's the code:

```
Cities = new Mongo.Collection('cities');

Cities.insert({
    name: 'Oslo'
});

Cities.insert({
    name: 'Helsinki'
});

Contact = new SimpleSchema({
    city: {
        type: String,
        allowedValues: Cities.find().map((e) => e.name) // written ES6-style for readability; in fact, here goes an ES5 anonymous function definition
    }
});
```

What it does is explicitly binds currently existing cities from `Cities` collection to `Contact` schema's certain field's allowed values, so it's then impossible to store any other value than `"Oslo"` or `"Helsinki"`.

But when posting a [quickForm](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform), the field (`select`, actually) has no options.

If I rewrite the mapping function to

```
(e) => {
    console.log(e);
    return e.name;
}
```

then I get

```
I20150911-18:07:23.334(4)? { _id: 'GLAbPa6N4W4c9GZZh', name: 'Oslo' }
I20150911-18:07:23.333(4)? { _id: 'vb64X5mKpMbDNzCkw', name: 'Helsinki' }
```

in server logs, which makes me think the mapping function is correct.

At the very same time, doing all this in Mongo console returns desirable result:

```
production-d:PRIMARY> db.cities.find().map(function (e) { return e.name; });
[ "Oslo", "Helsinki" ]
```

What do I do wrong? Is it impossible to fill the simple-schema's `allowedValues` array at the run time?

Comment: There is no options and probably no allowed value as well. At the time the simpleschema is initiated, collections are not so the call returns nothing. Maybe you can find a workaround by changing the load order.