# Simple Schema valid values lists

Tags: meteor, simple-schema

I'm using Simple Schema, and I'd like to have a way to validate the values in some fields against a predefined list or against another

Validate against a predefined, not changing list (like an enum). This could probably be done with a complicated regex but this doesn't feel right:

```
dialogType: {
   type: String,
   label: "Dialog Type",   // 'article', 'sentence','exercise','lesson','word'
   optional: false
},
```

Validate against the user collection, potentially with some filters applied:

```
userId: {
    type: String,
    label: "User ID",
    optional: false
 }
```

A related question
[Bind allowedValues to values from a collection in simple-schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32525570/bind-allowedvalues-to-values-from-a-collection-in-simple-schema)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess you can do it as follows:

```
dialogType: {
    type: String,
    allowedValues: ['article', 'sentence','exercise','lesson','word'],
    optional: true
},
```

Did you look at https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema#allowedvalues